# Remainder and quotient in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

I am a beginner in Latin and I write most of my math lectures in Latin. I searched at Wikipedia and other sites but I can't find any translation of these words.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I don't think the Roman authors have much to say about such things. A good place to look is Gauss's  Disquisitiones Arithmeticae of 1801,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quotient is *quotus*, the remainder is *residuum*.

[This](https://books.google.de/books?id=ROBiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=false) textbook titled *Elementa arithmeticae singularis et universalis* lays it out in very simple terms:

> Dividere est ex producto duorum factorum et ex uno eorundem alterum invenire.
>
> Productum cognitum vocatur *dividendus*.
> Factor cognitus vocatur *divisor*.
> Factor incognitus vocatur *quotus*.

(Click the link and read on, it is *really* an elementary introduction. I did not find an equally explicit definition of *residuum* in the book, but it is clear from context.)

I think they're all masculine because *numerus* is implied.  ​The same terminology is also definitely used by Euler.

Instead of *quotus*, you are also liable to encounter, surprise, *quotiens*. See [this](https://books.google.de/books?id=psxJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q&f=false) definition by Leibniz:

> Divisio est subtractio aequalium [...] in divisione, dato facto sive numero rerum, seu dividendo, quaeritur numerus repetitionum alterius rei seu divisoris; is numerus dicitur quotiens.

Of course, if you have a *fractio*, the dividend is the *numerator* and the divisor the *denominator*.

Comment: A happy find. Is there any indication of who is the author of this primer?

Comment: @fdb A fellow named [Johann Conrad Blank](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Conrad_Blank), who sadly is not primarily remembered for his pedagogical works but for being the victim in a sensational murder case.

Comment: I wonder if there may be circumstances where *quotus* (/ *quotiens*) will be mistaken as a ordinary interrogative word